# Android Game Debugs Fine but Crashes when Downloaded from Play Store

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have published a simple game to learn the publishing process, Popprz, on both Apple and Google developed using Cocos2d-x.

The downloaded & installed game runs happily on some devices, Huawei P10 & Samsung Galaxy 10 for example, but crashes on a Samsung S6 & Honor 8 Pro.

When I try to debug the issue from Android Studio I find I can happily debug the same app on, for example, the Samsung S6 & Honor 8 Pro - no problems :[

Can anyone suggest how I should try and identify the problem(s)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to run this on an emulator and produce the same results? If so, try looking at the logcat to see the issue. If you are still stumped, please post the logcat.

Comment: Try to run release build on those devices and analyze logcat.

Comment: Ok, I will try and run the release build from AS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to 'see' the error using a Release Build in Android Studio on one of the problem phones.   A linker error on a random method.

My problem was a much too high target sdk/api level.  Once I changed this from 28 => 21 (I also changed my minSdkVersion to 21) the app runs Ok.

Thanks for the pointers.